# Issues with order of scanner.Scan() when using multiple scanners

Tags: go, buffer

For some background, I'm pretty new to Go, but the person who wrote this program at work left so the code is my responsibility now. This program wraps a CLI tool that writes to stdout and stderr. We want to process the output while also gracefully handling the errors of the underlying tool.

This is the relevant snippet of code that is currently being used:

```
cmd := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)

stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

cmd.Start()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
errScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)

for errScanner.Scan() {
        err := errScanner.Text()
        log.Fatal(err)
}

for scanner.Scan() {
        // proccess stdout data
}

if scanner.Err() != nil {
        log.Fatal(scanner.Err())
}

cmd.Wait()
```

Normally this works fine. However, if the size of the data written to standard out exceeds buf.MaxScanTokenSize which is 64 KB then the program just hangs with no errors. The underlying command finishes, but neither of the scanner for loops are hit. I found that if I swap the position of the errScanner.Scan() and scanner.Scan() then the issue no longer occurs. This is what I mean:

```
cmd := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)

stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}

cmd.Start()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
errScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)

for scanner.Scan() {
        // proccess stdout
}

for errScanner.Scan() {
        err := errScanner.Text()
        log.Fatal(err)
}

if scanner.Err() != nil {
        log.Fatal(scanner.Err())
}

cmd.Wait()
```

Does anyone know why the initial problem is happening and why the swapping the two scanners fixes it? My guess was that the two scanners were sharing the same underlying buffer which could be causing some problems, but I created two different buffers and assigned them to the scanners and it didn't fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is written, your program will wait until all data is read from one of the streams, depending on the order. If while reading from that stream the second stream buffer fills, the running program (the one whose output you're reading) will block because it cannot write any more output to that stream.

It looks like you are not really handling the errors, so you can read the error stream in a goroutine:

```
go () {
  for errScanner.Scan() {
     ...
  }
}()

for scanner.Scan() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense and clears up a lot of my questions. Thanks!